# Access $scope in other function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i access my $scope.key out side this function?

```
.controller('CatsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) {

      var query = firebase.database().ref().orderByKey();
      query.once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            $scope.key = childSnapshot.key;
            // I need this value
            $scope.childData = childSnapshot.val();

            $scope.data = $scope.childData.Category;

            console.log($scope.key);
          });
        });

      console.log($scope.key);
      // returns undefined

        var ref = firebase.database().ref($scope.key);
          ref.once("value")
            .then(function(snapshot) {
              console.log(snapshot.val());
              var name = snapshot.child("Category").val();
              console.log(name);
            });
  })
```

I've tried it with $scope.apply but this did not work.

Comment: After the function has run you can access `$scope.key`

Comment: no, for some reason it's undefined also after the function is run.

Comment: Show us the complete controller code

Comment: updated the question...

Comment: The function you run is asynchronous, it will run after your console.log statement

Comment: Hmm, what can i do then that i can use the key value in my other request?

Comment: @oliver that is a async operation and next immediate line of code runs before it completes. So, causes undefined.

Comment: That means i have to chance to get the value key? What options do i have?

Comment: I need this value for the second request @Jai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase you need the `childSnapshot.key` in your second call, you should access it in the promise success callback:

```
query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        $scope.childData = childSnapshot.val();

        $scope.data = $scope.childData.Category;

        var ref = firebase.database().ref(childSnapshot.key);
        ref.once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
          var name = snapshot.child("Category").val();
          console.log(name);
        });
      });
    });
```

Note that this will run for each iteration since the `childSnaphot` object is in the `forEach` callback